# Async issue when changed method to use collection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, c#-5.0, async-await

I had a method like that:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Model>> Get(string link)
{
   MyRequestAsync request = new MyRequestAsync(link);
   return await request.GetResult();
}
```

It is working pretty well.

Then I decided to change this one a little bit:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Model>> Get([FromUri]IList<string> links)
{
    IList<Model> list = new List<Model>();
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        MyRequestAsync request = new MyRequestAsync(link);
        list.Add(await request.GetResult());
    }

    return list;
}
```

And now I am got a problem, for some reason it is just not returning the result. For my understanding I am getting the deadlock.

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to "await yield return DoSomethingAsync()"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061761/is-it-possible-to-await-yield-return-dosomethingasync)

Comment: @Fals, doesn't seem related.  He's not using yield.

Comment: If you posted a small but complete example that reproduced the problem, we'd be able to help you better.

Comment: Pause the debugger to see what's on the stack. Were does execution halt? Probably some blocking code in `GetResult`.

Comment: Your first method won't even compile, so how come you say it's working?

Comment: It doesn't look like a deadlock, try passing in a list of just one url and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Add ConfigureAwait(false) to not deadlock on the UI Thread.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Model>> Get([FromUri]IList<string> links)
{
  IList<Model> list = new List<Model>();
  foreach (var link in links)
 {
     MyRequestAsync request = new MyRequestAsync(link);
     list.Add(await request.GetResult().ConfigureAwait(false));
}

return list;
```

Answer (score -3):

Give this a try:

```
IList<Model> list = new List<Model>();
```

to

```
ConcurrentBag<Model> list = new ConcurrentBag<Model>();
```

Often times using async and await can get confusing (for me, at least) and will produce results that I'm unsure of. This is the first thing I swap out when I have trouble.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think that [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) (“I don't know what this does, but it worked for me once, so it may work for you too, even if the situation is different”) is a good practice. And I don't see any reason why this change should help here.